# azure-cosmosdb distinct query "Request timed out"

Tags: mongodb, distinct, azure-cosmosdb

I have 127k documents in a windows7 local DB if I do a db.coll.distinct() it returns instantly.

When I do the same on CosmosDB it returns:

```
globaldb:PRIMARY> db.ross3.distinct("region");
2018-03-29T19:25:30.010-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: distinct failed: {
        "_t" : "OKMongoResponse",
        "ok" : 0,
        "code" : 16500,
        "errmsg" : "Request timed out.\r\nActivityId: 5d48dde5-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.21.
0",
        "$err" : "Request timed out.\r\nActivityId: 5d48dde5-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.21.0.

} :
DBCollection.prototype.distinct@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1745:1
@(shell):1:1
```

Comment: Other queries: db.ross3.count(),    db.ross3.findOne() return data

Comment: post your code here

Comment: Please post your sample code to let me help you.

Comment: The code is there:    db.ross3.distinct("region");